# Calling managed C++/CLI from native C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++-cli

Is it possible for a native C++ dll to call C++/CLI code?

I want to access C# code in C++ unit test. For this I created one C++/CLI wrapper(CLR dll). I am successfully able to instantiate C# class in C++/CLI. But when I am instantiating C++/CLI class in C++ Unit test class I am getting run-time error "Failed to set up execution context to run the test". When I removed code of invoking C++/CLI class then dummy test cases are passing.
Everything is building successfully but only at run-time unit test cases are failing.

```
UnitTestSetup.cpp

namespace UnitTest
{
   UnitTestHelperSetup::MockSetup *g_mockSetup;
   TEST_CLASS(TestSetup)
   {
      TEST_METHOD(TestMethodSetup)
      {
        g_mockSetup= new UnitTestHelperSetup::MockSetup();
        // other code...
      }
   }
}
-----------------------------------------------------------------

UnitTestHelperSetup.cpp(CLR project)

#ifndef UNITTESTHELPERS_OPT_EXPORTS
#define UNITTEST_OPT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#else
#define UNITTEST_OPT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

namespace UnitTestHelperSetup
{
   class MockSetup
   {
       UNITTEST_OPT_API MockSetup();
       // other code...
   }
}
```

Comment: Haven't worked for quite a while with MS managed code – but if I remember right, you need the CLR available for being able to run managed code, which isn't loaded by unmanaged exe, though. You need to do that explicitly by some means.

Comment: Found an article at [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607352/Injecting-NET-Assemblies-Into-Unmanaged-Processes) that possibly might help you, or [MS hosting documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/index).

Answer (score 0):

Found solution here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unit-tests-fail-with-error-failed-to-set-up-the-ex/120965#T-N336346

You need to disable the SafeDLLSearchMode in the registry by creating the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\SafeDllSearchMode (DWORD) and setting it to 0.